# Problem with line numbering in BMC Journal template

Tags: line-numbering

I am re-formatting a manuscript submitted to the **BMC Medical Informatics and Decision Making Journal**.  To format the manuscript I used the  [bmcart.cls](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex) template provided by the BMC journal. It is suggested the manuscript with line numbers to guide the revision process, i.e:

```
\documentclass [linenumbers, doublespacing]{bmcart}
```

The template adds line numbers in both margins of the document as in the picture below:

[image: sample output]
However, the editor is now requesting line numbers in just one side of the text, since "numbers on both sides make the article unpleasant to read". Also as you can see there is not enough space between the line numbers and the text of the manuscript.

I contacted the customer support without any response. I must resubmit the manuscript very soon.

Thanks in advance for your help.

The sample text file is included below:

Sample text:

```
\documentclass [linenumbers, doublespacing]{bmcart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support

\def\includegraphic{}
\def\includegraphics{}



%%% Put your definitions there:
\startlocaldefs
\endlocaldefs
%%% Begin ...
\begin{document}

%%% Start of article front matter
\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{fmbox}
\dochead{Research}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% Enter the title of your article here     %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{My article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% Enter the authors here                   %%
%%                                          %%
%% Specify information, if available,       %%
%% in the form:                             %%
%%   <key>={<id1>,<id2>}                    %%
%%   <key>=                                 %%
%% Comment or delete the keys which are     %%
%% not used. Repeat \author command as much %%
%% as required.                             %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author[
   addressref={aff1},                   % id's of addresses, e.g. {aff1,aff2}
   corref={aff1},                       % id of corresponding address, if any
   noteref={n1},                        % id's of article notes, if any
   email={jane.e.doe@cambridge.co.uk}   % email address
]{\inits{JE}\fnm{Jane E} \snm{Doe}}
\author[
   addressref={aff1,aff2},
   email={john.RS.Smith@cambridge.co.uk}
]{\inits{JRS}\fnm{John RS} \snm{Smith}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% Enter the authors' addresses here        %%
%%                                          %%
%% Repeat \address commands as much as      %%
%% required.                                %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\address[id=aff1]{%                           % unique id
  \orgname{Department of Zoology, Cambridge}, % university, etc
  \street{Waterloo Road},                     %
  %\postcode{}                                % post or zip code
  \city{London},                              % city
  \cny{UK}                                    % country
}
\address[id=aff2]{%
  \orgname{Marine Ecology Department, Institute of Marine Sciences Kiel},
  \street{D\"{u}sternbrooker Weg 20},
  \postcode{24105}
  \city{Kiel},
  \cny{Germany}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% Enter short notes here                   %%
%%                                          %%
%% Short notes will be after addresses      %%
%% on first page.                           %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{artnotes}
%\note{Sample of title note}     % note to the article
\note[id=n1]{Equal contributor} % note, connected to author
\end{artnotes}

\end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% The Abstract begins here                 %%
%%                                          %%
%% Please refer to the Instructions for     %%
%% authors on http://www.biomedcentral.com  %%
%% and include the section headings         %%
%% accordingly for your article type.       %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{abstractbox}

\begin{abstract} % abstract
\parttitle{First part title} %if any
Text for this section.

\parttitle{Second part title} %if any
Text for this section.
\end{abstract}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% The keywords begin here                  %%
%%                                          %%
%% Put each keyword in separate \kwd{}.     %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{keyword}
\kwd{sample}
\kwd{article}
\kwd{author}
\end{keyword}

% MSC classifications codes, if any
%\begin{keyword}[class=AMS]
%\kwd[Primary ]{}
%\kwd{}
%\kwd[; secondary ]{}
%\end{keyword}

\end{abstractbox}
%
%\end{fmbox}% uncomment this for twcolumn layout

\end{frontmatter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% The Main Body begins here                %%
%%                                          %%
%% Please refer to the instructions for     %%
%% authors on:                              %%
%% http://www.biomedcentral.com/info/authors%%
%% and include the section headings         %%
%% accordingly for your article type.       %%
%%                                          %%
%% See the Results and Discussion section   %%
%% for details on how to create sub-sections%%
%%                                          %%
%% use \cite{...} to cite references        %%
%%  \cite{koon} and                         %%
%%  \cite{oreg,khar,zvai,xjon,schn,pond}    %%
%%  \nocite{smith,marg,hunn,advi,koha,mouse}%%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% start of article main body
% <put your article body there>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Background %%
%%
\section*{Content}
Text and results for this section, as per the individual journal's instructions for authors. %\cite{koon,oreg,khar,zvai,xjon,schn,pond,smith,marg,hunn,advi,koha,mouse}

\section*{Section title}
Text for this section \ldots
\subsection*{Sub-heading for section}
Text for this sub-heading \ldots
\subsubsection*{Sub-sub heading for section}
Text for this sub-sub-heading \ldots
\paragraph*{Sub-sub-sub heading for section}
Text for this sub-sub-sub-heading \ldots
In this section we examine the growth rate of the mean of $Z_0$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. In
addition, we examine a common modeling assumption and note the
importance of considering the tails of the extinction time $T_x$ in
studies of escape dynamics.
We will first consider the expected resistant population at $vT_x$ for
some $v>0$, (and temporarily assume $\alpha=0$)
%
\[
 E \bigl[Z_1(vT_x) \bigr]= E
\biggl[\mu T_x\int_0^{v\wedge
1}Z_0(uT_x)
\exp \bigl(\lambda_1T_x(v-u) \bigr)\,du \biggr].
\]
%
If we assume that sensitive cells follow a deterministic decay
$Z_0(t)=xe^{\lambda_0 t}$ and approximate their extinction time as
$T_x\approx-\frac{1}{\lambda_0}\log x$, then we can heuristically
estimate the expected value as
%
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eqexpmuts}
E\bigl[Z_1(vT_x)\bigr] &=& \frac{\mu}{r}\log x
\int_0^{v\wedge1}x^{1-u}x^{({\lambda_1}/{r})(v-u)}\,du
\nonumber\\
&=& \frac{\mu}{r}x^{1-{\lambda_1}/{\lambda_0}v}\log x\int_0^{v\wedge
1}x^{-u(1+{\lambda_1}/{r})}\,du
\nonumber\\
&=& \frac{\mu}{\lambda_1-\lambda_0}x^{1+{\lambda_1}/{r}v} \biggl(1-\exp \biggl[-(v\wedge1) \biggl(1+
\frac{\lambda_1}{r}\biggr)\log x \biggr] \biggr).
\end{eqnarray}
%
Thus we observe that this expected value is finite for all $v>0$ (also see \cite{koon,khar,zvai,xjon,marg}).



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% Backmatter begins here                   %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{backmatter}

\section*{Competing interests}
  The authors declare that they have no competing interests.

\section*{Author's contributions}
    Text for this section \ldots

\section*{Acknowledgements}
  Text for this section \ldots
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                  The Bibliography                       %%
%%                                                         %%
%%  Bmc_mathpys.bst  will be used to                       %%
%%  create a .BBL file for submission.                     %%
%%  After submission of the .TEX file,                     %%
%%  you will be prompted to submit your .BBL file.         %%
%%                                                         %%
%%                                                         %%
%%  Note that the displayed Bibliography will not          %%
%%  necessarily be rendered by Latex exactly as specified  %%
%%  in the online Instructions for Authors.                %%
%%                                                         %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% if your bibliography is in bibtex format, use those commands:
\bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys} % Style BST file
\bibliography{bmc_article}      % Bibliography file (usually '*.bib' )

% or include bibliography directly:
% \begin{thebibliography}
% \bibitem{b1}
% \end{thebibliography}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                               %%
%% Figures                       %%
%%                               %%
%% NB: this is for captions and  %%
%% Titles. All graphics must be  %%
%% submitted separately and NOT  %%
%% included in the Tex document  %%
%%                               %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%
%% Do not use \listoffigures as most will included as separate files

\section*{Figures}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{\csentence{Sample figure title.}
      A short description of the figure content
      should go here.}
      \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{\csentence{Sample figure title.}
      Figure legend text.}
      \end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                               %%
%% Tables                        %%
%%                               %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Use of \listoftables is discouraged.
%%
\section*{Tables}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Sample table title. This is where the description of the table should go.}
      \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
           & B1  &B2   & B3\\ \hline
        A1 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3\\
        A2 & ... & ..  & .\\
        A3 & ..  & .   & .\\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                               %%
%% Additional Files              %%
%%                               %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section*{Additional Files}
  \subsection*{Additional file 1 --- Sample additional file title}
    Additional file descriptions text (including details of how to
    view the file, if it is in a non-standard format or the file extension).  This might
    refer to a multi-page table or a figure.

  \subsection*{Additional file 2 --- Sample additional file title}
    Additional file descriptions text.


    \end{backmatter}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be *their* problem, not yours. However, you can accomplish the annoying editor's wish by adding the following magic to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\set@numberlines@box{\rlap}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Where? I'd say just before the silly `\def\includegraphic{}` line.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your fast and helpful response. That way I don't need to make changes in the bmcart.cls file

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

In the load packages section I add `\usepackage{lineno}`

Then just in front of the background section, I add the command `\linenumbers`

These line numbers, however, extend all the way to the end of the document, including the Additional files section, References, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, I would write a comment but I don't have the reputation to do so...

I am also fighting with this template, in my case because it only shows the first author's affiliation on the title page (as seen above), but the editor somehow requires all affiliations on the title page.

I asked the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610258/bmc-journal-template-only-showing-first-author-editor-requires-all), but I thought that maybe the original author of this question could give me an idea of how he or she overcame this issue.