# BMC Journal template only showing first author, editor requires all

Tags: titles, journal-publishing, journal

I recently submitted my first paper to BMC Bioinformatics journal and had formatted everything according to their author guidelines, using their own template ([Overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/biomed-central-article-template/gcgcxphtpccx), [Their own page](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/submission-guidelines/preparing-your-manuscript)). Then, my submission got declined because the pdf produced by their own template doesn't show all author affiliations on the title page, but only the first author's affiliation. The rest of the affiliations is shown after the main part of the manuscript. They somehow require all authors' affiliations to be shown on the title page, even though their own template does not allow this. I asked the assistant editor twice how to resolve this problem, but got no answer for a month and counting.

My question is: can I somehow tweak the template so it shows all authors on the first page or should I just reformat my  paper to use the article class?

Thanks in advance for your help/advice!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the template on overleaf is the same as on the journals page? In any case unless the journal sends you to a template on overleaf, I'd probably use the template the journal provides.

Comment: @daleif Actually, for my submission I used the one from the journals page, I just included the Overleaf template as an example since it seems to be identical. To make this clear, the problem occurs with both the Overleaf version and the version from the journal page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  `BioMed_Central_Tex_Template_v1.06` provided by [BioMedCentral LaTeX template](https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/18360804/data/v1)

**(1)** For one column add before `\end{fmbox}%`

```
% ********************************** % added <<<<<
\begin{artnotes}  
\printaddress{aff1}

\printaddress{aff2}
\end{artnotes}
% **********************************

\end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout
```

[image: a]

**(2)** For two column add before `%\end{fmbox}}% comment this for two`

```
% **********************************  % added <<<<<
\begin{artnotes}
    \printaddress{aff1}
    
    \printaddress{aff2}
\end{artnotes}
% **********************************

%\end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout
```

[image: b]

Comment: If you're commenting `\end{fmbox}`, shouldn't you comment `\begin{fmbox}` somewhere as well?

Comment: @Teepeemm Of course!  It is part of the template instructions for a twocolumns article.  Like  `\documentclass[twocolumn]{bmcart}% uncomment this for twocolumn layout` etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton Simon! There is just the problem now that it shows 3 and 4 instead of 1 and 2 if I do it that way. I worked around the issue, which I will detail in an answer. Actually, the answer to my problem was already there, I just didn't know it. But just like the [linenumber bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227362/problem-with-line-numbering-in-bmc-journal-template) solution, now it is out there if someone else wonders, too.

Comment: @fratajcz Delete any old .aux file before compiling or use a new empty working directory.

Answer (score 2):

Just as detailed in Simon's answer, the solution is to place the affiliations in between the `\begin{artnotes}` and  `\end{artnotes}`. However, if I do it using `\printaddress{aff1}` and `\printaddress{aff2}` for affiliation 1 and 2, it will up the counter and display it as affiliations 3 and 4. So, to keep the correct affiliation numbering I sadly had to hard-code them and use the `\note` command:

```
% ********************************** % added <<<<<
\begin{artnotes}  
\note{$^1$Department of Zoology, Cambridge, London, UK.}

\note{$^2$Marine Ecology Department, Institute of Marine Sciences, Kiel, Germany.}
\end{artnotes}
% **********************************
```

while placing them in the document exactly as Simon describes.